# Android API to get saved Loyalty Cards

Tags: android, payment, android-pay

We have Loyalty Card feature in our Android App. Creating and Saving Loyalty Card to Android Pay App is working fine.

We followed the below link - 
https://developers.google.com/pay/save/guides/loyalty/get-started-android. It uses Android API.

Assume that using our App, User Saves two Loyalty Cards to Android Pay App. These will be reflected in the Android Pay App.

**Is there any Android API to get these saved Loyalty cards?**

For Adding the Loyalty card we have Android API - `CreateWalletObjectsRequest`.

I went through the android pay document but I didn't find any Android API to get Loyalty card
**Reference :** https://developers.google.com/pay/save/reference/v1/

But to get the Saved Loyalty Cards we have REST API - https://developers.google.com/pay/save/reference/v1/loyaltyclass/list.

Now my question is - **is there any Android API to get saved Loyalty Cards or We need to use the REST API ?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. You have to use the REST API to list the wallet objects. You can see the full Android docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/CreateWalletObjectsRequest).